# How can a process modify the sigmask of another one?

Tags: unix

I know that if i want to modify the sigmask of a calling process i can use sigprocmask(). Can this syscall be used to modify an other process mask?

Comment: *Why* do you need to do that? What is the *real* problem that you need to solve? Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly, don't tag multiple programming languages unless you're actually are actively programming using all in the same project, or are comparing languages.

Comment: A debugger might be able to do it but otherwise (in the normal run of things) it can’t be done.

Comment: Well `sigprocmask` sets the mask of the current process. So if you can inject into the process somehow then you can call it from the context of that process.